# Cannot install go package go.net/html

Tags: go, installation

I use go.net/html in my project on work and everything is ok. But when I try to install this package on my laptop I get a error:

```
termith@termith-laptop:~/go$ go get code.google.com/p/go.net/html
# code.google.com/p/go.net/html
src/code.google.com/p/go.net/html/token.go:304: undefined: io.ErrNoProgress
```

My system:

```
termith@termith-laptop:~/go$ uname -a
Linux termith-laptop 3.2.0-51-generic-pae #77-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 24 20:40:32 UTC 2013
i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your version of `go`?

Comment: I have updated my go, it was a problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely have an outdated Go version (see for example [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery/issues/22)).

Check the output of `go version` and update if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Beware: the go.net package [url will change with Go 1.4](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-announce/eD8dh3T9yyA):

```
code.google.com/p/go.net => golang.org/x/net
```

If you update (again) your go version (to 1.4, once released, November 9th, 2014), you might have to change that import path.

See "[Go 1.4 subrepo renaming](http://golang.org/s/go14subrepo)".